# Syntax to check if dir exists then remove is not working in yml file

Tags: ansible, yaml

In looper (built on top of jenkins), I had to define shell scripts in yml format to execute a job.

I am a beginner in YAML. While all other commands like echo, wget works. Checking if a folder exists then remove the dir is throwing an error when i try to execute the looper job.

I have flows defined in yaml file, and in one flow, I gave the below line to check if that folder exists then remove it

```
- [[ -d "$WORKSPACE/codometer-runner" ]] &&  rm -r $WORKSPACE/codometer-runner
```

It is giving me below error:

expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found &
10:06:00  in 'reader', line 34, column 47:
10:06:00      ... WORKSPACE/codometer-runner" ]] &&  rm -r $WORKSPACE/codometer-runner
10:06:00                                          ^

Can some please tell me how else i can verify if folder exists in YAML?

Comment: YAML is generic markup language. You should rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

In YAML, `[` starts a flow sequence. Thus, you cannot have a plain scalar starting with `[`. You have several options:

- Use a block scalar:

  ```
  - >-
     [[ -d "$WORKSPACE/codometer-runner" ]] &&  rm -r $WORKSPACE/codometer-runner
  ```

  (The `>` starts a folded block scalar, the succeeding `-` tells YAML to not append the trailing newline).
- Single-quote the scalar:

  ```
  - '[[ -d "$WORKSPACE/codometer-runner" ]] &&  rm -r $WORKSPACE/codometer-runner'
  ```
- Double-quote the scalar:

  ```
  - "[[ -d \"$WORKSPACE/codometer-runner\" ]] &&  rm -r $WORKSPACE/codometer-runner"
  ```

  Since the scalar contains double quotes, you need to escape them.

Comment: found the answer..Thanks.